# Websphere Jython AdminConfig.modify with comma as value causes exception

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8

I have a script which sets the JVM properties on a WebSphere server. The script works perfectly unless the value contains a comma. I can't seem to find a work around for this. Does any one know of a way around this?

Example code

```
def SetJVMProp(jvm):
    attr_name  = ['name', 'globalDataFil ter.stockcount.maintenance']
    attr_value = ['value', 'FUEL,DELETED_PRODUCTS,MERCH_AND_PURCH_GROUP']
    attr_required = ['required', "false"]
    attr_description = ['description', '']
    attr_list = [attr_name, attr_value, attr_required, attr_description]
    property=['systemProperties',[attr_list]]
    AdminConfig.modify(jvm, [property])
```

Exception:

```
Unexpected error:  <type 'com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException'>com.ibm.ws .scripting.ScriptingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:java.lang .IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "]"  not found. Attribute=value had invalid value=FUE for input parameter ['name'"globalDataFilter.stockcount.maintenance"]  ['value'"FUE",DELETED_PRODUCTS,MERCH_AND_PURCH_GROUP'] ['required' 'false'] ['description' '']
```

Websphere: 8.5.5
Jython: 2.5.4rc1

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dots? Also there is a space there.
Try :
'globalDataFilter\.stockcount\.maintenance'

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine (on version 9.0, but wouldn't think that would matter).   Maybe try typing into a different editor?  Could you have copied an unprintable char in there or something odd like that??

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried the code i put above it works for me too. The code im using is slightly different as im passing the strings to  SetJVMProp, so somthing is happening when i pass the string over eg def SetJVMProperty(jvm, name, val):
        print(val);
        attr_name  = ['name', name]
        attr_value = ['value', val]

Comment: Never mind i had a moment of madness and tried changing the encoding of the string and now it works perfectly. attr_value = ['value', val.encode('iso-8859-1')]

Comment: But thanks Everyone :)